# find and mark the local minima and maxima of matrix surfice

Tags: matlab, matrix

I got an assignment to generate a random matrix `(MXN)` and to present it as a surface. After that, I have to find and mark the local minima and maxima. I'm not sure how to do this.

So I managed to create the random matrix and present it by using:

```
M = randi([0 9],4,4); 
surf(M)
```

First problem is that I used:

```
lmaxM = islocalmax(M)
lmaxI = find(lmaxM)
```

It's not working that good, for example:

For the Matrix:

M=

```
 0     8     7     4
 1     1     9     7
 6     9     2     8
 3     5     4     1
```

The `islocalmax(M)` gives me this logical variable:

```
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0
   1   1   0   1
   0   0   0   0
```

But I supposed to get instead:

```
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0
   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0
```

---

Anyway, after getting the logical matrix , I pulled out the indexes of the values of `1` by using:

```
lmaxI = find(lmaxM);
```

What should I do next in order to present the values on the surface??

That's the code I got til now:

```
clear
M = randi([0 9],4,4)
surf(M)
lmaxM = islocalmax(M)
lmaxI = find(lmaxM)
lminM = islocalmin(M)
lminI = find(lminM)
```

Thanks;

Answer (score 0):

The function `islocalmax` is capable to find local maxima along the specified dimension.

> By default, `islocalmax` operates along the first dimension whose size does not equal 1.

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox you can use [`imregionalmax`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregionalmax.html).

Answer (score 0):

From matlab references, it states that

[localmaxima](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/islocalmax.html)
[localminima](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/islocalmin.html)

**Syntax of islocalmax()**

```
TF = islocalmax(A)  
TF = islocalmax(A,dim)  
TF = islocalmax(___,Name,Value)  
[TF,P] = islocalmax(___)
```

Description

> example TF = islocalmax(A) returns a logical array whose elements are 1 (true) when a local maximum is detected in the corresponding
>   element of an array, table, or timetable.
>
> TF = islocalmax(A,dim) specifies the dimension of A to operate along.
>   For example, islocalmax(A,2) finds local maxima of each row of a matrix A.

**Syntax of islocalmin()**

```
TF = islocalmin(A)  
TF = islocalmin(A,dim)  
TF = islocalmin(___,Name,Value)  
[TF,P] = islocalmin(___)
```

Description

> example `TF = islocalmin(A)` returns a logical array whose elements are 1 (true) when a local minimum is detected in the corresponding
>   element of an array, table, or timetable.
>
> example `TF = islocalmin(A,dim)` specifies the dimension of A to operate along. For example, islocalmin(A,2) finds local minima of each
>   row of a matrix A.

So if the matrix have more than one value you should specify the dimension also. So the second syntax will resolve the issue.

```
lmaxM = islocalmax(M,4)
lminM = islocalmin(M,4)
```